# Criação de DropDownListFor com view tipada

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlist

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou iniciando meus estudos na arte do ASP.NET C#.
Estou com problemas em criar um DropDownListFor.

Como estou fazendo:
 - Estou usando ADO.NET
 - tenho meu modelo Equipamento
 - tenho uma viewmodel EquipamentoEmpresa, apenas pra listar todas as empresas(id e descrição).
 - na minha controller do Equipamento, na action Inserir, eu crio o seguinte:

```
  ViewBag.ListaEmpresa = new SelectList(
                                        new EmpresaDAO().ListaEmpresaDropDown().ToList(),
                                                   "EmpresaId",
                                                   "CodEmpresa"
                                                );
```

- Essas são algumas das formas que já tentei fazer a criação do ddl, porém sem sucesso:

```
@model Objects.ValueObjects.EquipamentoVO

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmpresaId, new SelectList((ViewBag.ListaEmpresa) as SelectList, "EmpresaId", "CodEmpresa"), "Selecione uma empresa")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmpresaId, new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaEmpresa, "EmpresaId", "CodEmpresa"), "Selecione uma empresa")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmpresaId, new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListaEmpresa,"ListaEmpresa", "CodEmpresa"), "Selecione uma empresa")
<br>
```

Alguém saberia me indicar onde estou errando? ou me passar uma ideia de como criar um ddl com uma view tipada?

Comment: Explique melhor o erro, talvez descrever melhor o que acontece quando roda ou passar o texto que vem no erro.

Comment: Essa é a mensagem que ocorre 
Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' não contém uma propriedade com o nome 'EmpresaId'. Em uma das formas que eu fiz, ele trouxe o numero correto de dropdown, só nao trouxe registros, apareceu o nome do componente

Comment: coloque .Value no final e tente novamente

Comment: Em qual parte eu coloco o .Value?

Comment: Na parte que deveria aparecer os registros , aonde você falou que estava aparecendo os nomes dos componentes

Comment: esse é o código que aparece o nome do objeto  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmpresaId, new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaEmpresa, "CodEmpresa"), "Selecione uma empresa")

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmpresaId, new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaEmpresa.Value, "CodEmpresa"), "Selecione uma empresa")

Comment: tb não deu certo  Additional information: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' não contém uma definição para 'Value'

Comment: hmmm, tenho quase certeza que o problema está nesse ViewBag.ListaEmpresa, tente achar nele o que você quer mostrar e colocar .NomeDaInfo pra não retornar o nome do objeto.
Substitua a parte .Value da minha mensagem anterior com esse .NomeDaInfo que você deseja exibir e veja se retornam as propriedades que você quer